# How to find header and footer of generated openssl key and what is the value of public key

Tags: security, openssl, cryptography

Hello friends I got a task from my univerzity at home and i don't know how to answer on some questions. I appreciate it some help.

1.First of all i have to generate key with open ssl library

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 1024
```

Question: What is the method used to create a key? ( I think RSA?)

2. Cat private.pem
   Question: What is the header and footer of file
   Output:

```
cat private.pem 
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

3. Question: what is value of public key

```
openssl rsa -in private.pem -text

Output:
Private-Key: (1024 bit)
modulus:
    00:97:cf:e5:68:f9:ee:a6:5f:81:c1:31:67:61:9a:
    62:e9:6d:e4:21:95:18:4e:f8:87:bc:29:02:e6:16:
    56:ce:28:75:9a:49:e2:89:60:91:76:d6:26:9d:68:
    d2:9d:65:4c:55:48:24:a9:14:73:ef:7d:db:fb:2a:
    d9:a2:5e:3e:b1:70:62:1a:15:04:4a:65:b7:80:7a:
    94:ce:8a:8c:29:20:12:2f:ca:e9:dc:04:c9:3a:f8:
    fa:e4:21:1d:14:2e:22:dd:82:64:59:cb:9c:55:bb:
    2d:e9:2f:9f:1f:e0:6c:05:fd:97:b2:7d:e1:c3:33:
    38:b4:24:10:19:d3:56:e8:b3
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent:
    62:a9:f1:de:0c:f9:66:55:91:fd:de:3e:e3:37:34:
    6b:a3:48:ed:ee:79:52:f1:c1:3d:af:a5:bb:a5:ef:
    1a:a3:3e:f3:5c:6b:87:7f:24:6b:08:79:26:3a:77:
    0f:66:43:7a:f5:9d:25:ea:2e:03:0b:58:49:df:aa:
    7c:15:26:46:a9:94:de:42:53:48:c5:3b:86:92:27:
    dc:ba:64:ff:4c:96:55:51:1a:99:53:03:8b:e0:d3:
    c0:fe:33:e5:d8:2b:c0:57:c5:79:be:eb:90:0f:9b:
    70:14:80:6f:f6:f4:6c:a6:62:07:5b:08:22:00:b7:
    43:59:0b:ca:d6:1f:f3:c1
prime1:
    00:c5:53:35:7d:e7:2f:63:6b:92:4f:aa:3d:01:7f:
    09:c1:81:1e:ee:f9:e2:ab:7e:f4:4e:70:3c:c3:62:
    3a:f9:b8:96:60:ab:a2:5f:44:f4:6b:22:17:c1:0d:
    05:dc:3c:12:b0:3e:65:b7:67:d4:20:87:bc:4e:58:
    d3:98:11:6e:e1
prime2:
    00:c4:f4:25:d0:51:33:ef:d9:56:71:8f:45:85:44:
    31:03:29:bd:f6:1c:f3:fe:f1:63:a3:d4:8a:59:29:
    a3:30:67:13:c6:a2:a7:c1:fe:4c:e9:95:92:62:27:
    fa:c7:2f:86:aa:6d:6e:23:77:46:ef:01:8e:0b:58:
    7d:cc:47:6e:13
exponent1:
    7c:4d:42:71:21:65:14:b7:fa:de:fc:5a:99:ca:b1:
    16:98:84:27:fe:79:ef:96:75:c7:c3:a4:43:60:69:
    ce:4d:9d:4d:20:51:94:ba:17:4e:35:97:c9:20:af:
    04:61:43:54:8a:ba:00:a3:03:59:ca:a7:b0:a2:fc:
    07:db:53:81
exponent2:
    00:a8:9e:0d:b1:a7:93:bb:88:6a:c5:96:4f:82:a4:
    bb:01:66:3f:47:f1:c9:c3:3e:8e:7b:b8:7f:29:8e:
    c8:33:ac:4b:f6:07:53:70:76:73:0a:98:0f:57:11:
    bb:55:c4:8e:9a:62:4d:a4:f7:7d:37:2a:31:9d:ed:
    08:e6:57:51:19
coefficient:
    22:bd:19:46:91:c3:41:09:36:9e:d7:f9:09:07:d0:
    78:a9:b8:87:52:43:17:9e:cb:6e:b2:1a:ed:c8:4b:
    8c:66:11:91:28:47:18:29:3f:f6:d2:76:0a:8b:de:
    e2:d9:cd:3a:96:df:a7:f3:c0:35:12:6b:9c:48:38:
    20:d2:bd:4f
writing RSA key
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: You need to understand a little bit about RSA to answer #3, the first two are rather obvious and you even answered the first one. I'll give you hint on #3: there are eight components, some of them are considered the public key and some are considered part of the private key, and one component overlaps and is considered part of both. You need to identify all the components that are considered part of the public key.

Comment: i did it alredy but thx

Comment: Becouse of corona we are self studying so it is little bit harder to doing new stuff you don''t see or work with them before

Comment: Looks like you figured out the answer, congrats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 1024bit RSA
2. -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   3.Public key is modulus + public Exponent
   modulus:
   00:97:cf:e5:68:f9:ee:a6:5f:81:c1:31:67:61:9a:
   62:e9:6d:e4:21:95:18:4e:f8:87:bc:29:02:e6:16:
   56:ce:28:75:9a:49:e2:89:60:91:76:d6:26:9d:68:
   d2:9d:65:4c:55:48:24:a9:14:73:ef:7d:db:fb:2a:
   d9:a2:5e:3e:b1:70:62:1a:15:04:4a:65:b7:80:7a:
   94:ce:8a:8c:29:20:12:2f:ca:e9:dc:04:c9:3a:f8:
   fa:e4:21:1d:14:2e:22:dd:82:64:59:cb:9c:55:bb:
   2d:e9:2f:9f:1f:e0:6c:05:fd:97:b2:7d:e1:c3:33:
   38:b4:24:10:19:d3:56:e8:b3
   publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)